# semicolon/curly bracket syntax error in java

Tags: java, methods, syntax, interface

When I try the below code, I get the following exception:

> Syntax error on token ";", { expected

```
public int getValue(int row, int column) ;
    return row + column;
```

But when I change it to the below code, I get this exception:

> Abstract methods do not specify a body

```
public int getValue(int row, int column) {
    return row + column;
}
```

How can I write this without getting a syntax error?

Comment: You don't implement methods in interfaces (unless they are static or default methods and you are using Java 8), you implement them in classes.

Comment: This must be in an interface. You need to look up what you can and can't do in interface method declarations.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 1):

I made an example that is working, I hope it helps. If you have any questions most comment will try to help.

```
public class Test {
    private int array[][] = new int[10][10];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.getValue(1, 5));
        System.out.println(test.getValue2(2, 3));   
    }

    //Get the value of parameters
    public int getValue(int row, int column){
        return (row+column);
    }
    //Get the value of an attribute
    public int getValue2(int row, int column){
        return array[row][column];
    }

}
```

If you are wanting to make a statement on an interface it looks like this:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    default int getValue(int row, int column){
        return row + column;
    }
}
```

If this is the goal then you have some architectural problem, but I think it's just the name "interface" instead of "class."

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an interface class, thats why you are getting "Abstract methods do not specify a body" error. Please go through this link, It may give you good understanding about [interface in java.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm)